# There is a horseshoe with positive measure

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, real-analysis

Here is a theorem by Bowen :
[image]

My question is about the highlighted part in the picture. why there such a function $g$ exist?

Comment: The construction is too lengthy to be read, but aren't you merely speaking about an increasing function from a segment to another segment? And then the rest should be in comparing the lengths of these two segments?

Answer (score 2):

The point is that you construct $g$ interval by interval, and then need to check that the function you are left with is continuously differentiable. It's obviously continuously differentiable in the interior of any one of the intervals, so the real question is about continuous differentiability at a point in the Cantor set (what's left after the interiors are removed). This is why the derivatives of the functions are chosen to get uniformly close to $\gamma$ on the entire intervals as the size of the intervals shrinks to 0 ($\beta_n/\alpha_n\to\gamma$).

Comment: Thank you Anthony Quas. But for each $\underline{a}$ how is this function $g:I_{\underline{a}}^*\to J_{\underline{a}}^* $ defined?

Comment: just write down a polynomial with the right conditions (maps endpoints to the right places; has the right derivative at the end). You should be able to do it with a cubic (I haven't checked)